# Enable Pino Logging at a Particular Level

Tags: javascript, logging, pino

From researching the web, the proper way to enable logging at a certain level is by adding the 'level' attribute to the object passed into the pino constructor.  The documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/master/docs/api.md#level-string).

However, per my logging configuration `logger_config.js`

```
import pino from "pino";

const send = function (level, logEvent, a, b) {}; 

const logger = pino({
   level: "trace",
   browser: {
      serialize: true,
      asObject: true,
      transmit: {
         send,
      },  
   },  
});

export default logger;
```

and logging usage, which contains a second way to set the level,

```
import logger from "../../logger_config";

export const myComponent = async (formData) => {
   logger.level = "trace";
   logger.error("ERROR");
   logger.info("INFO");
   logger.debug("DEBUG");
```

I was expecting the debug statement to print.  Only the error and info level statements are printed.  Furthermore, if I add a `trace` level debug statement, it gets printed, along with `info` and `error`; however, there is still no `debug` statement.

What's even more odd is that when the `level` is set to `debug`, "logger level is `debug`" from the following statement gets printed.

```
   if (logger.levelVal === 20) {
      console.log("logger level is `debug`");
   }
```

I've restarted node after changing the `level` setting.

How do I get the debug statement to print (i.e. have everything at the `debug` level and above to print)?